# Change DependencyProperty on the ControlTemplate

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I have a Button with two different images - one for normal state and one - for `PointerOver` state:

```
public sealed class MyButtonTwo : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ImageSource", typeof (ImageSource), typeof (MyButtonTwo), new PropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource)));

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource) GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSource2Property = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ImageSource2", typeof (ImageSource), typeof (MyButtonTwo), new PropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource)));

    public ImageSource ImageSource2
    {
        get { return (ImageSource) GetValue(ImageSource2Property); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSource2Property, value); }
    }
```

I am using this property in the Control Template in the Style:

```
<Image x:Name="Image"                      
        Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}" />
```

In the style I can change the properties of the MyButton:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
      <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
        <Storyboard>
          <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="FullGrid">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
```

But I can not change my dependency property such way:

```
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Storyboard.TargetName="Image">
   <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{TemplateBinding ImageSource2}"/>
```

Only one way I have found is to add two different Images on the Template and change Visibility of them.

May be there is any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with a regular Binding instead of a TemplateBinding:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source"
                               Storyboard.TargetName="Image">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
        Value="{Binding ImageSource2,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```